# Python import dir management

Tags: python, django, import, module

I am working on a project in python combined with Django. I copied an existing module from the internet and my files are organized in the following way:

```
\myproj\
    \rtool\
           \dns\
                 file1.py
                 file2.py
                 file3.py
                 file4.py
                 file5.py
                 (many py files)


     mytool.py
```

In many of the files in the `dns` folder has `import dns.somefile` where `somefile` is a file that is also in the `dns` folder and it causes many errors. 
While I don't want to start editing file by file. I am looking for a command to put in `mytool.py` that is under `myproj` folder, (command or `sys.path.insert`)so I won't get an error while some of the many python files has an `import dns.file1` line in them

Comment: Instead of cpying the dns module into your project tree, you should simply install in (to your system or virtualenv), so it will be available under its expected name.  Alternatively, you can mess around with your `PYTHONPATH`, which I don't recommend.

Comment: the problem that the dns is not an independent module?